# PHP Function - Is using ! possible to state that this function is false, as in !function('blah')

Tags: php, boolean-logic

I am working with a simple function that returns true when checking if a user has an appropriate account type.

```
function userHasType($type)
{
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pathTo/db.connection.php';

    $accNum = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['accountNum']);
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $type);

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
            INNER JOIN user_types ON users.id = userId
            INNER JOIN types ON typeId = types.id
            WHERE users.id = '$accNum' AND types.id='$type'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if (!$result)
    {
        $error = 'Error searching for user types.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if ($row[0] > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The function is named userHasType, i currently use this function like this:

```
$userHasType = userHasType('thisAccount');
.......
if ($userHasType AND whatever) {
```

I would like to use a statement where basically, if the user does not have a specific type, then this will happen, else something else will happen.

As in:

```
if (!$userHasType AND whatever) {
```

or im guessing this would actually work:

```
$userNotHasType = !userHasType('thisAccount');
.......
if ($userNotHasType AND whatever) {
```

Which ever way though, what is the right way to go about this... Because I have tried both and for some reason it is not reacting the way i would expect it to. It would be due to something else, but my conclusion is that both these ways must not work.

So some clarity on the matter would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Thank You!!

```
if (!$userHasType) {
    $prPrice = ($prPrice2 != 0 && $userIsLoggedIn ) ? $prPrice2 : $prPrice1;
    } else {
    $prPrice = ($prPrice2 != 0 && $userIsLoggedIn ) ? $prPrice2Incl2PIncl : $prPrice1Incl2PIncl;
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried any of these before deciding whether they work or not?

Comment: You should really be using `&&` rather than `AND`. Anyway, the `!` operator should work fine as long as the function is returning TRUE or FALSE. Any other values may equate either way.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, as i stated, in my post, i have tried both of these, and for some reason the script is not reacting the way i would expect it to... My conclusion is that they do not work, it was not a decsion, merely my contemplation... in anycase,did you read my post?

Comment: How is it "not reacting" properly? Maybe if you told us what the `whatever` part is, we could help. Because as it stands now, your code should work just fine.

Comment: *"it is not reacting the way i would expect it to"* - Please clarify as this appears to be the heart of your problem. If you work up a small, reproducible block of code with clear inputs and expected outputs I guarantee you'll have an answer within minutes.

Comment: @Polynomial: `and` is perfectly valid and works identically to `&&`, except it has a slightly lower precedence.

Comment: @Polynomial Sorry, yes, it is like that in the script, i put it as and when retyping it in here.

Comment: @Marc B Please see the edit in my post. For some reason, it is working the opposite way around, which leads me to believe that the else bit is being triggered.

Comment: @MarcB - Sure, but 99% of developers use `&&`, so it's best to get into the habit of using what is most prevelant to make it easier to conform to a particular style convention later on (e.g. in industry or a large project).

Comment: @Poly: and 99% of drivers use the brake pedal instead of the e-brake, but both can slow down/stop the car. Just because it's not used often doesn't make it any less valid.

Comment: @Blackberry: better brush up on boolean logic, then. If you're swapping your trues and falses, then it's your code doing so, not PHP making a mistake.

Comment: @Marc I was not intending to come across as implying that php is making a mistake, rather that i am having trouble with the idea of whether this is possible or not, which i am taking it, that it is? In which case, you are right, my mistake must be in something else. But im not sure 100% of whether my code is right or wrong so, hence the confusion.

Comment: @MarcB - I never said it was less valid, I was just stating that since at some point he's going to have to conform to a strict style, it's best to get into the habit of using what's generally considered to be standard practice. I could use the (:?) ternary operator in C# to handle nulls, but the standard is to use the null coallescing operator. Both produce the exact same IL, but the standard is still there.

Comment: @Marc B Could you see my replies in the post below and possibly provide some insight there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you CAN use the ! operator in front of a function call and you will get the boolean negative of the function call's return value, and you can do the same to a variable.

Looking at your function code, it seems to me that type.id might be an integer, rather than a string-type value such as a varchar or text. What does the database show as the type for the column id in the types table?

As mentioned by Polynomial, I suggest you avoid using `AND`. `&&` is usually a better choice when you are dealing with normal precedence situations.

About the use of variables; I think it is good practice to minimize the use of extra variables when reasonable. Of course IMHO this decision is subject to the amount of use the variable has. I suggest sticking with:

```
if (!$userHasType && whatever) {
```

or if you do not use `$userHasType` anywhere else then just go ahead and use the function call in-line:

```
if (!userHasType('thisAccount') && whatever) {
```

Comment: It appears that the right variable is being passed. I think Marc B cleared up polynomials' statment. I am adding this as an extra varible as the function will be called hundreds of times each user query otherwise. But basically, my question was can i do this -> `!userHasType('thisAccount')`

Comment: @ghbaratt or rather... this : `!$userHasType` given the previous declaration.

Comment: @BlackberryFan Yes, (I edited my answer) so long as you have set $userHasType to be the return value of the function call then it will be set to the boolean negative of the returned value.

Comment: Legend, makes perfect sense, thank you so much :) Now for the million dollar question... Why does everyone feel the immense need to downvote my simple question? Lack of understanding or what?

Comment: @BlackberryFan You included too much backstory and irrelevant content. As I said in the comments above you could have provided a very simple proof-of-concept example (5 lines max) and had a fast, concise response. i.e. Can I use `!` with functions in control statements: `function foobar() return false; if (!foobar()) print 'success!';`. Remove the extra irrelevant information like queries, file includes etc. We don't need to know anything about your application.. only that your function is returning false. For the record, those downvotes aren't mine.